# Dynamically changing wx.Dialog wx.CLOSE_BOX style

Tags: wxpython

I'd like to create a wx.Dialog window where I can dynamically make the window have a wx.CLOSE_BOX style but be able to temporarily disable it and have it look disabled while it's unavailable.  I know that inside the control's message handler I need to be mindful of the wx.EVT_CLOSE event and skip, ignore, or veto it appropriate for the state I am in, but I would like the little X in the title bar to visually reflect my state also.

I currently do this when I want to turn off the CLOSE_BOX:

```
    style = self.GetWindowStyle()
    self.SetWindowStyle(style & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX))
```

and I do this when I want to turn it back on:

```
    style = self.GetWindowStyle()
    self.SetWindowStyle(style | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
```

and even though I can tell that the updates to the style integer DO seem to be happening, no disabling of the actual dialog window's X button seems to be happening.  Does anyone know the easy way to do what I am trying to do?  Here's a screen capture of the change I am trying to dynamically make in a dialog box:

[image]

Comment: So far as I can tell, all wx.CLOSE_BOX does it specify a "Close" and "Help" button instead of, say, an "OK" and "Cancel". Could you give a bit more detail about what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that style cannot be changed after window creation. According to the documentation:

> Also, please notice that not all styles can be changed after the
>   control creation.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowtogglewindowstyle

Here's a simple test I used:

```
import wx

def toggle(window):
    print window.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.CLOSE_BOX)
    window.Refresh()
    wx.CallLater(2000, toggle, window)

def main():
    app = wx.App(None)
    window = wx.Dialog(None)
    toggle(window)
    window.ShowModal()
    window.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To be clear, FogleBird is saying that you can't change the style I want changed (i.e. the example code he provided shows that it doesn't actually work)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague about what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming you want to prevent people from closing your dialog while your application performs some task.

`wx.CLOSE_BOX` is just a style. I experimented creating dialogs both with and without `wx.CLOSE_BOX` and all it did was change which buttons were at the bottom of the dialog. Even if I didn't set `wx.CLOSE_BOX` there was still an OK button which would close the window. Beyond that, what about the X button? What about Alt+F4?

Your best option is probably making your own custom panel, creating your own "Close" button and then calling `Enable(False)` until you finish your process. However, this still won't stop users from clicking the X button or hitting Alt+F4. For that, you need to catch `wx.EVT_CLOSE`. Look at this example:

```
class CustomDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)

        self.closeButton = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_CLOSE,"Close")
        self.closeButton.Enable(False) #initialize the button as disabled

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose, id=wx.ID_CLOSE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)
        #wx.EVT_CLOSE is triggered by the X button or Alt+F4

    def onClose(self, event):
        if self.closeButton.IsEnabled():
            #if we want to allow the user to close the dialog

            #do something

            event.Skip() #allow this event to close the window

    def reenableButtom(self):
        self.closeButton.Enable(True)
```

You can then manually call `self.reenableButton()` when your process ends or you can bind it to an event.

The `self.closeButton.IsEnabled()` check is very important because remember that `self.onClose()` isn't just bound to the button. We want to make sure the dialog behaves the same no matter if the user clicked the "Close" button, clicked the X button, or hit Alt+F4. `event.Skip()` lets the even propogate upwards. Allowing `wx.EVT_CLOSE` to propogate will close the dialog. Therefore, it is very important that we do not call this line unless we want to close the window.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness.  I've tried to correct that.  Thanks for the detailed work-around code also.  I already knew how to handle that stuff on the inside, and I'm sorry I wasn't more clear about the fact that I was looking for how to control the presentation of the close button that's in the title bar.